# Current scaling problem in Ubuntu on high dpi displays

Tags: gnome, display-resolution

A couple of days ago, the [Fedora Asahi Remix](https://asahilinux.org/fedora/) for Apple Silicon-based Macs was fully released. While I appreciate the efforts of the Fedora and KDE communities, my personal preference has always leaned towards GNOME and Ubuntu over Fedora and KDE. About a year ago, I attempted to run [Ubuntu on my 2020 M1 MacBook Air](https://github.com/UbuntuAsahi/ubuntu-asahi), and the overall experience was fantastic, except for one significant issue – the challenge of adjusting to 200% scaling due to the high DPI display.

For me, 200% scaling resulted in larger font sizes than I prefer. Interestingly, KDE Plasma's 175% scaling emerged as the "sweet spot" for my Mac, surpassing the fractional scaling solutions of other desktop environments/window managers. However, this scaling compromise adversely affected my vision over prolonged computer use, making it challenging to engage with my device for extended periods.

While some Ubuntu users on similar machines may not have encountered the same fractional scaling issue, individual preferences and experiences vary. As I contemplate upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10, I'm keen to understand whether there have been improvements in the Fractional Scaling solution. The absence of proper Fractional Scaling, not just for GNOME but across various desktop environments/window managers, leading into 2024, seems silly and requires prompt attention.

I'm particularly interested in knowing if the regular Fractional Scaling still consumes excessive resources. Seeking a solution to replicate the Fractional Scaling of Plasma with Ubuntu/GNOME is paramount to my user experience. Insights into this matter would be highly appreciated.

Keep in mind when providing solutions that they better work on Wayland, as these Apple Silicon based Macs explicitly require Wayland to function well, as X11 is basically dead.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, you can enable fractional scaling on Ubuntu 20.04 and newer versions by going to Settings -> Displays and toggling the Fractional Scaling switch. This will allow you to choose scaling factors between 100% and 200%, such as 125%, 150%, or 175%. However, this feature is experimental and may have some performance or quality issues1.
If you want to use Wayland, which is recommended for Apple Silicon based Macs, you can enable fractional scaling by using this command in the terminal: gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features " ['scale-monitor-framebuffer']". This requires GNOME 3.32 or higher1. You can also use dconf-editor to manually set the scaling factor to any integer value, such as 250%2.
If you want to use X11, which is the default session on Ubuntu, you can enable fractional scaling by using this command in the terminal: gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features " ['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']". This requires Ubuntu 19.04 or higher1. However, this may result in increased CPU and GPU usage13.
I hope this helps you fix the fractional scaling issue on your Ubuntu/GNOME system